# Flutter - How to change the text in bottom navigation from child widget?

Tags: flutter, bottomnavigationview

I started Flutter recently and my app required bottom navigation. I have created bottom navigation and manage to access the child widget based on the tab selected.

Under the child widget there is drop down selection where I can change the bottom navigation text in one of the tabs for different selections.

I have tried a few days but still could not figure out how the child widget can change the text.

I have tried callback but cannot get it work. I have tried navigation.push - material page route but it rebuild the whole widget and my selection gone. I have also tried to use GlobalKey or Sharedpreference to capture my selection so that when it rebuild, it will use back the stored selection but I couldn't get it work.

I only wish to change the bottom navigation text in one of the text from child widget drop down selection.

Which is the best method to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you try to use the bloc pattern with a StreamBuilder. I have an example below. Regardless, in the example there is a stateful widget, a bloc, and a data class. Try to understand this code and modify it to your needs.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class StreamScaffold extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StreamScaffoldState createState() => _StreamScaffoldState();
}

class _StreamScaffoldState extends State<StreamScaffold> {
  ScaffoldDataBloc bloc;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    bloc = ScaffoldDataBloc();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<ScaffoldDataState>(
        stream: bloc.stream, // The stream we want to listen to.
        initialData: bloc.initial(), // The initial data the stream provides.
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          ScaffoldDataState state = snapshot.data;

          Widget page;
          if (state.index == 0) {
            // TODO separate this into its own widget, this is messy.
            page = Center(
              child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: () => bloc.updateText(state,"Sales"),
                        child: Text("Set text to Sales")

                    ),
                    RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: () => bloc.updateText(state, "Purchases"),
                      child: Text("Set text to Purchases"),
                    )
                  ]),
            );
          }

          if (state.index == 1) {
            // TODO separate this into its own widget, this is messy.
            page = Center(
                child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () => bloc.updateText(state, "Stock"),
                    child: Text("Set text to Stock"),
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () => bloc.updateText(state, "Budget"),
                    child: Text("Set text to Budget"),
                  )
                ]));
          }

          return Scaffold(
            body: page,
            bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
                currentIndex: state.index,
                onTap: (int) => bloc.updateIndex(state, int),
                items: [
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
                      // Obtain the text from the state
                      title: Text(state.variableText)),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow), title: Text("Test")),
                ]),
          );
        });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    bloc.dispose();
  }
}

// A data class to hold the required data.
class ScaffoldDataState {
  int index;
  String variableText;

  ScaffoldDataState({this.index = 0, this.variableText = "Hello"});
}

// A bloc to handle updates of the state.
class ScaffoldDataBloc {
  StreamController<ScaffoldDataState> scaffoldDataStateController = StreamController<ScaffoldDataState>();
  Sink get updateScaffoldDataState => scaffoldDataStateController.sink;
  Stream<ScaffoldDataState> get stream => scaffoldDataStateController.stream;

  ScaffoldDataBloc();

  ScaffoldDataState initial() {
    return ScaffoldDataState();
  }

  void dispose() {
    scaffoldDataStateController.close();
  }

  // Needs to be called every time a change should happen in the UI
  // Add updated states into the Sink to get the Stream to update.
  void _update(ScaffoldDataState state) {
    updateScaffoldDataState.add(state);
  }

  // Specific methods for updating the different fields in the state object
  void updateText(ScaffoldDataState state, String text) {
    state.variableText = text;
    _update(state);
  }

  void updateIndex(ScaffoldDataState state, int index) {
    state.index = index;
    _update(state);
  }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Additional Questions from comment:

The easiest solution would be to simply pass the bloc as a parameter to the widget. Create a new dart file in your project, create a StatelessWidget there, create the code for the page in the build method. Note: it would make sense for you to separate the bloc into its own file along with the data class.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// Import the file where the bloc and data class is located
// You have to have a similar import in the parent widget. 
// Your dart files should be located in the lib folder, hit ctrl+space for 
// suggestions while writing an import, or alt+enter on a unimported class.
import 'package:playground/scaffold_in_stream_builder.dart'; 


class ChildPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final ScaffoldDataBloc bloc;
  final ScaffoldDataState state;

  const ChildPage({Key key, this.bloc, this.state}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(); // TODO replace with your page
  }
}
```

However, if the these child widgets get their own children in separate files it would be better to use a InheritedWidget instead, with the bloc and state. This avoids "passing state down". See this [article on inherited widgets](https://medium.com/@mehmetf_71205/inheriting-widgets-b7ac56dbbeb1)

Comment: Thanks. It works. If I were to put the widget page into it's own widget in another file, can it be done? Different navigation bottom tab will have different coding and could be lengthy. How can the child widget access bloc.updateText(state,"Sales") in another file? if I place it at another file, it shows "bloc" and "state" undefine name.

Comment: Thanks. I used your code and encounter the following error when using the method updateText(state, "sales") on another dart file. The state is "null".

flutter: The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
flutter: The method 'updateText' was called on null.
flutter: Receiver: null
flutter: Tried calling: updateText(null, "Sales")

Comment: Have you passed the state and bloc in the parameters of the ChildPage in the main dart file? Like: ChildPage(bloc: bloc, state: state)

Comment: Yes. Above are code from the updated files. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome  No problem 